# Get list of column names containing specific value SQL-Hue

Tags: sql

I have 50 tables and I want to get list of all column names containing specific value in the column.

Something like: `if 'Test' in column give me the column name`. And I want to apply it for all 50 tables

Tables names are: abc1,abc2,abc3, … abcn.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Which database? Because this looks like you need a procedure type thing to do this. Getting column name from somewhere and use it in SQL query cant be doable from one single SQL

Answer (score 0):

There must be a better way to do this, but I did come across a query like this from a colleague a couple of years ago and I found the below (or a script similar to below that i may have tweaked before sending onto him) somewhere online (I imagine here on SO, but can't see to find where - I will update with link to original source if i can find it).

I would also just point out that this is a very heavy proc so I would take a backup of your db and restore it to a dev or test environment before executing it. Or even execute it against a test db that you might have in your localdb. The script searches all columns of all tables in a selected db for a string.

Personally I would probably export the data from each table to txt or csv and do a Find within them.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE FindMyData_String
        @DataToFind NVARCHAR(4000),
        @ExactMatch BIT = 0
    AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

        INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
        SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
        FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
                INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                    ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
            AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'
                And Data_Type In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


    DECLARE @i INT
    DECLARE @MAX INT
    DECLARE @TableName sysname
    DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
    DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @DataExists BIT
    DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                                THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                              From   ReplaceTableName
                                              Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                           = ''' + @DataToFind + '''
                                              )
                                         Set @DataExists = 1
                                     Else
                                         Set @DataExists = 0'
                                ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                              From   ReplaceTableName
                                              Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                           Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%''
                                              )
                                         Set @DataExists = 1
                                     Else
                                         Set @DataExists = 0'
                                END,
            @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
            @i = 1

    SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
    FROM   @Temp

    WHILE @i <= @MAX
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
            FROM    @Temp
            WHERE   RowId = @i


            PRINT @SQL
            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

            IF @DataExists =1
                UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

            SET @i = @i + 1
        END

    SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
    FROM    @Temp
    WHERE   DataFound = 1
    GO
```